# How to get the value value from soap response using apache camel?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, apache-camel

I want get the value of AddResult i.e 100 from below soap response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>100</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Below is the java code:

```
package com.learncamel.routes.xmlxstream;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.xstream.XStreamDataFormat;

import com.learncamel.domain.AddResponse;

public class XmlResponseToObject extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, String> reference = new HashMap<String, String>();
        reference.put("AddResponse ", AddResponse.class.getName());

        XStreamDataFormat xstreamDataFormat = new XStreamDataFormat();
        xstreamDataFormat.setAliases(reference);
        xstreamDataFormat.setPermissions(AddResponse.class.getName());

        try { 
            from("direct:xmlinput")
            .log("Received Message before unmarshal is ${body} and Headers are ${headers}")
            .unmarshal(xstreamDataFormat)
            .log("Received Message after unmarshal is ${body} and Headers are ${headers}")
            .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true");
       } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }       
    }
}
```

Below is the junit code:

```
package com.learncamel.routes.xmlxstream;

import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XmlResponseToObjectTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    public RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new XmlResponseToObject();       
    }   

    @Test
    public void unMarshalTest() throws InterruptedException{
        //AddResponse addresponse=new AddResponse();
        String input="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><AddResult>100</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
        template.sendBody("direct:xmlinput",input);
    }
}
```

Below is the POJO:

```
package com.learncamel.domain;



public class AddResponse {

    private String AddResult;

    public String getAddResult() {
        return AddResult;
    }

    public void setAddResult(String addResult) {
        AddResult = addResult;
    }
}
```

### Stacktrace

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: Envelope
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1486)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1454)     at
>   org.apache.camel.dataformat.xstream.AbstractXStreamWrapper.unmarshal(AbstractXStreamWrapper.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:541)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:506)
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168)
>     at
>   com.learncamel.routes.xmlxstream.XmlResponseToObjectTest.unMarshalTest(XmlResponseToObjectTest.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)  at
>   org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)   at
>   org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static Document loadXMLString(String response) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));

    return db.parse(is);
}

public static List<String> getFullNameFromXml(String response, String tagName) throws Exception {
    Document xmlDoc = loadXMLString(response);
    NodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(nodeList.getLength());
    for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node x = nodeList.item(i);
        ids.add(x.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());             
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
    return ids;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
{

    String res="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><SubtractResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><SubtractResult>150</SubtractResult></SubtractResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    List<String> output = XmlResponseToObject.getFullNameFromXml(res, "SubtractResult");
    String[] strarray = new String[output.size()];
    output.toArray(strarray);
    String x = output.get(0);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with camel

Answer (score 2):

You can try using xpath to extract values from xml like:

```
 .convertBodyTo(org.w3c.dom.Document.class)
 .setProperty("needValue",xpath("*//AddResult/text()",String.class))
  //use extracted value
```

If you need to transform input xml to another look for xslt component.

Upd: if you really need to work with objects to remove your exception you need to extract mapped body AddResponse cause you mapped it. Your input string starts from not mapped soap element "Envelope". If you have CxfPayload before .unmarshall() just convert it to Document or String. For successfully test just remove soap elements.